# an error of accessing Netezza SQL database from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, netezza

Although the similar questions had been asked here many times, this question occurred in environment different from others.

From Visual studio 2012 professional, when I accessed database by NetezzaSQL driver (through C# code), i got error:" **Data source name not found and no default driver specified**".

My desktop is 64bit win7 and the connection string is

```
  Driver={NetezzaSQL};Server=xxxxxxxxxx;Database=myTool;Uid=myUser;Pwd=myWord;ReadOnly=false;"
```

I found that we have NetezzaSQL driver for ODBC(64 bit) but we do not have ODBC (should be 32 bit) driver.

If I change the build property target platform as any CPU, I got the above error.

If I change the build property target platform as x64, I got error "remote endpoint was not reachable."

I can access the database from Aginity netezza workbench with the same above connection string without any problems from my desktop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Netezza is IBM and should have the driver you want online.  If I remember right, Netezza appliances don't exist without a support contract with IBM either, you should be able to contact your netezza rep and get the driver there as well.

Comment: @Twelfth, I think I have the support contract from IBM because I can access the DB from my desktop by Aginity Netezza Workbench. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I use a connection that is slightly different, making sure to include the `System.Data.Odbc` namespace and I can connect fine. VS2012

```
"Driver=NetezzaSQL; Server=xx.xxx.xx.xxxx; Port=5480; Database=dbname; Persist Security Info=true; UID=username; PWD=pword"
```